# Error while Compiling Subversion with a custom-compiled Apache on a shared server

Tags: apache-httpd, compiling, subversion, apr

Am using a RHEL 5.5 shared server, my user has complete access to /opt folder.
No root access, cant write to /etc, /usr etc. 
So, I downloaded httpd-2.4.6 and httpd-2.4.6-deps onto /opt (ie. /opt/httpd-2.4.6)
I installed Apache on /opt/httpd.
By using `./configure --prefix=/opt/httpd --with-included-apr`
It installed and worked w/o any issues.

Then, I wanted to setup this Apache with mod_dav_svn, So i downloaded subversion 1.6.23(i prefer svn 1.6) from Apache site.
But when i compile subversion with
`./configure --prefix=/opt/svn --with-apr=/opt/httpd/bin/apr-1-config --with-apr-util=/opt/httpd/bin/apu-1-config --with-ssl --with-apxs=/opt/httpd/bin/apxs`

I got this error:

```
checking whether Apache version is compatible with APR version... no
configure: error: Apache version incompatible with APR version
```

I googled on the error, which mentioned i need to use latest version of APR, but the apr i used was from the httpd-2.4.6-deps.tar.bz2 
I checked the version in /opt/httpd-2.4.6/srclib/apr/CHANGES, it was 1.4.8, Isnt it latest?

Can anyone tell me whats the source of the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that the issue was a mistake with handling double quotes in `configure` file of the source of subversion.
I had to compare the line which gave the mismatch error with the `configure` file in subversion 1.7.14.
I had to change the line

```
$EGREP "[apache_minor_version= *"$apache_minor_version_wanted_regex"]" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
```

to

```
$EGREP "apache_minor_version= *\"$apache_minor_version_wanted_regex\"" >/dev/null 2>&1; then :
```